# Saving docs in methods in node.js with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a structure issue with node.js and mongoose

My model file looks like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema ({
     val: String
});

mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test');
```

And I'm trying to make a method that updates test.val.

```
testSchema.methods.update = function update ( val ) {
 this.val = val;
 // problem spot
}
```

The spot labelled problem spot is where my issue is. I need some way of updating the document 'this' with the value inputted to the method - ideally with the outcome of being able to call it as `testObject.update(val);` to update my doc.

In my controllers I have things like this set up fairly often with syntax similar to below:

```
var Test = mongoose.model('Test');
var updateData = {'val': '10};
Test.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':id}, updateData, function (err, result) {
 // error checking etc
});
```

And that works fine in my controller, but if I try to do something similar in a method I'm not able to because the schema technically isn't defined yet since the schema definition and method definition are in the same file.

TL;DR: `var Test = mongoose.model('Test');` fails inside methods so I don't know how to handle updating docs from within their own methods.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated... I feel like I'm just missing something super basic here.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to update the value in your model? Your model should define the fields and functions available for use and not attempt to modify the data. If this is for a webpage, your controllers should do all of the work  (with the exception of model validation and all of that) and thus they should be what is updating this value.

Comment: @RobertFines Ah - sorry I should have phrased that differently. Your point though make sense.  It just seems so convenient since you have the whole doc right there under the 'this' var and such. I guess I should never be modifying a document in it's own method?

Comment: I dont think that it is good practice to modify a document in its model. If there is a reason that you need to massage the data to fit your storage (or display) needs (i.e. format addresses, strip formatting from phone numbers, etc) I would do that in a setter for each individual field that needs it -- find an example here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html